# sometimes I unable to connect to connect to socket using php java bridge

Tags: java, php, sockets, php-java-bridge, java-bridge-method

we are using java bridge from PHP application to connect to java application.
But at times, connection get failed to connect. Below is the fucntion used to connect. I am not getting what the issue is. Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails to connect. Any persistent connection issues or count is set?

```
function open() {
            $errno = null;
            $errstr = null;
            $socket = JAVA_PERSISTENT_SERVLET_CONNECTIONS ?
                    pfsockopen("{$this->ssl}{$this->host}", $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 20) :
                    fsockopen("{$this->ssl}{$this->host}", $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 20);
            if (!$socket)
                throw new java_ConnectException("Could not connect to the J2EE server {$this->ssl}{$this->host}:{$this->port}. Please start it. Or define('JAVA_HOSTS', 8080); define('JAVA_SERVLET', false); before including 'Java.inc' and try again. Error message: $errstr ($errno)\n");
            stream_set_timeout($socket, -1);
            return $socket;
        }

     function java_HttpHandler($protocol, $ssl, $host, $port) {
            parent::java_SimpleHttpHandler($protocol, $ssl, $host, $port);
            try {
                $this->socket = $this->open();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $cogLink = "http://xxxx.xx.com/products/sup_products.asp?prod_id=81174";
    echo "eeeeerrrr";
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the exception/error log/response codes might help.

Comment: Yes, please try to give the "$errstr" message. Note: if you're using PHP7.1 and a recent javabridge, have a look to the soluble-japha client: http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/bridge_connection/ (set "use_persistent_connection"=true) and enable logger to see what happens. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Any persistent connection issues or count is set?

Most likely the back-end ran out of handles. Please note that, in order to obtain a persistent connection to a java "continuation", you'll have to send a servlet engine a POST request first. After that you can pfsockopen() to the java "continuation" the servlet engine has returned and use protocol request

(F p="A"/)

to recycle- and

(F p="F"/)

to put the "continuation" back to the pool.

I have checked the Java.inc code and it doesn't contain the code you have posted. Therefore I assume that you have written custom code to emulate Java.inc.

If so, please make sure to no exceed the bridge thread pool size (20 by default).